# initiate the post numbering for the upcoming articles at 100,000

Tags: posts

I've set up a new WordPress website, and it already contains 100 articles.

Now, I'm looking to initiate the post numbering for the upcoming articles at 100,000. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: post IDs are automatically assigned by your databases internal DB engine, not WordPress, your best bet is to create anmd delete new rows in the database table until you reach 99,999 . Note that post IDs aren't just for posts, they're used for revisions, drafts, pages, block templates, CPT's etc etc, so if you need sequential article IDs that start at 100k with no gaps then you cannot use post IDs. Importantly though, _why_ do you need this? What problem are you trying to solve by doing this? Is this a way to connect 6 number codes to posts? E.g. are these coupon IDs? Ticket numbers? etc etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tom says in the comments, post IDs are assigned by an AUTO_INCREMENT in the database. You can change or reset this with

```
ALTER TABLE wp_posts AUTO_INCREMENT=100000;
```

Comment: but I echo his questions why you want to do this.